# Windows CMD Start and wait for the default application in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to start the default application for a file, wait for it to complete, and then continue with my batch file. The problem is that start, when used below simply creates another command prompt window with the example.doc in the title bar. I can use call instead of start, but then call does not wait for the program to finish before going to the next line. It appears that start needs to have an executable name and will not work with the default application system in windows.

Any ideas how I can make this happen without having to hardcode the windows application in the batch file as well?

```
set filename=example.doc
start /wait %filename%
copy %filename% %filename%.bak
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it seems I have the choice of waiting for a program to finish with the start command, or I can call the default application for a data file, but I can't do both.

Comment: set filename=example.doc
call %filename%
copy %filename% %filename%.bak

Comment: what you're trying makes sense, well almost. MSWord returns immediately even with `/WAIT`. Try to do that with a `.txt` file you'll see that notepad (or notepad++) waits and it works. The problem is in the way MSWord launches (and returns without waiting to be closed)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hmm. I don't have word installed. Can you test my answer `open.cmd`? It works with libreoffice writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I start the default application for a file, wait for completion, then continue?

> It appears that start needs to have an executable name and will not work with the default application system in windows.
>
> `start`, when used below simply creates another command prompt window with the example.doc in the title bar
>
> ```
> start /wait %filename%
> ```

The above command won't work because `%filename%` is used as the window title instead of a command to run.

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Source [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Try the following command instead:

```
start "" /wait %filename%
```

---

#### Alternative solution using the default open command

> Any ideas how I can make this happen without having to hardcode the 
>   windows application in the batch file as well?

One way is to use `assoc` and `ftype` to get the default open command used for the file then execute that command.

The following batch file does that for you (so no hard coding of windows applications is needed).

**Open.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _file=example.doc
rem get the extension
for %%a in (%_file%) do (
  set _ext=%%~xa
  )
rem get the filetype associated with the extension
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%b in (`assoc %_ext%`) do (
  set _assoc=%%b
  )
rem get the open command used for files of type filetype
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%c in (`ftype %_assoc%`) do (
  set _command=%%c
  rem replace %1 in the open command with the filename
  set _command=!_command:%%1=%_file%!
  )
rem run the command and wait for it to finish.
start "" /wait %_command%
copy %_file% %_file%.bak 1>nul
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) - Display or change the link between a FileType and an executable program.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.

Comment: @KenWhite "Why are you formatting your response as a blockquote?" Huh? I wasn't. Rolled back. I missed blockquoting a single line of code quoted from the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the filename directly as command, unless that filename is a batch file, in which case use `call`.

In a batch file invocation of a GUI subsystem executable is blocking, unlike for an interactive command.

Use the `start` command when you ***don't*** want blocking execution.

---

There is a subtle point about “default application”, namely that a file type can have a registered default application for the graphical shell, e.g. its “Open with…”, without having an `assoc`/`ftype` association, or different from that association.

I'm not entirely sure of which registry entries are used for this. I've always had to look it up and research it each time. As I recall it's not well-documented.

But hopefully you're OK with just the `assoc`/`ftype` scheme.

---

A further subtle point about “default application”: on the laptop I'm writing this on the `ftype` association for text files is to open them in Notepad:

```
[H:\forums\so]
> assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile

[H:\forums\so]
> ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1

[H:\forums\so]
> _
```

And this is what the graphical shell (Windows Explorer) will do.

But `cmd.exe` looks inside files, and if it finds an executable signature then it tries to run the text file as an executable, even in Windows 10:

```
[H:\forums\so]
> echo MZ bah! >oops.txt

[H:\forums\so]
> oops.txt
This version of H:\forums\so\oops.txt is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

[H:\forums\so]
> _
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way around this problem of "running as executable" from the command line.  I have a file I can open via: %programpath% %fullpath%.ext successfully, but if I try to put "start /wait" in front it gives me the 16-bit error.  (Oh wait!! specifying `""` for title may have fixed it)

Comment: Why not just *not* use the `start` command. It's not necessary in a batch file. Keep it simple. :)